# dask.config.get cannot get anything?

Tags: python, dask

[Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html) has two families of task schedulers:

> Single machine scheduler: This scheduler provides basic features on a
>   local process or thread pool. This scheduler was made first and is the
>   default. It is simple and cheap to use, although it can only be used
>   on a single machine and does not scale Distributed scheduler: This
>   scheduler is more sophisticated, offers more features, but also
>   requires a bit more effort to set up. It can run locally or
>   distributed across a cluster

to get a better understanding, I am trying to reproduce some examples.

The [dask doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html) gives this example.

```
>>> import dask
>>> import dask.distributed  # populate config with distributed defaults
>>> dask.config.config
{
  'logging': {
    'distributed': 'info',
    'bokeh': 'critical',
    'tornado': 'critical',
  }
  'admin': {
    'log-format': '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  }
}

>>> dask.config.get('logging')
{'distributed': 'info',
 'bokeh': 'critical',
 'tornado': 'critical'}

>>> dask.config.get('logging.bokeh')  # use `.` for nested access
'critical'
```

I am trying to reproduce this.

`dask.config.config` worked well and gave this output.

```
{'temporary-directory': None,
 'array': {'svg': {'size': 120}},
 'distributed': {'version': 2,
  'scheduler': {'allowed-failures': 3,
   'bandwidth': 100000000,
   'blocked-handlers': [],
   'default-data-size': 1000,
   'events-cleanup-delay': '1h',
   'idle-timeout': None,
   'transition-log-length': 100000,
   'work-stealing': True,
   'worker-ttl': None,
   'preload': [],
   'preload-argv': [],
   'dashboard': {'status': {'task-stream-length': 1000},
    'tasks': {'task-stream-length': 100000},
    'tls': {'ca-file': None, 'key': None, 'cert': None}}},
  'worker': {'blocked-handlers': [],
   'multiprocessing-method': 'forkserver',
   'use-file-locking': True,
   'connections': {'outgoing': 50, 'incoming': 10},
   'preload': [],
   'preload-argv': [],
   'daemon': True,
   'profile': {'interval': '10ms', 'cycle': '1000ms', 'low-level': False},
   'memory': {'target': 0.6, 'spill': 0.7, 'pause': 0.8, 'terminate': 0.95}},
  'client': {'heartbeat': '5s'},
  'comm': {'compression': 'auto',
   'default-scheme': 'tcp',
   'socket-backlog': 2048,
   'recent-messages-log-length': 0,
   'timeouts': {'connect': '10s', 'tcp': '30s'}},
  'dashboard': {'link': '{scheme}://{host}:{port}/status',
   'export-tool': False},
  'admin': {'tick': {'interval': '20ms', 'limit': '3s'},
   'log-length': 10000,
   'log-format': '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
   'pdb-on-err': False}}}
```

although `>>> dask.config.get('logging')` gave this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ffda8dcb4de4> in <module>
----> 1 dask.config.get('logging')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/config.py in get(key, default, config)
    430         k = canonical_name(k, result)
    431         try:
--> 432             result = result[k]
    433         except (TypeError, IndexError, KeyError):
    434             if default is not no_default:

KeyError: 'logging'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that there is no top level "logging" entry.  it's within the "distributed" name, so you probably want

```
dask.config.get("distributed.logging")
```

The example in the docs is misleading in this way.  I've changed it in this PR: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5374

Comment: I came here because I get the same problem, and your solution doesn't work for me. I still get a KeyError using `dask.config.get('distributed.logging')`. If you look at the config dict in the OP's question it doesn't have a "logging" entry anywhere and I see the same on my system.